# problem importing async functions javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native, post, import, async-await

I am trying to edit my code in React Native because I need to reuse some functions in others screens, so I commented some lines in the screen I am attaching and create some new js files with the functions I am going to re-use in different screens. Before doing this my screen works fine, calling the different functions with async and await, waiting the first ones to get resolved to start executing the following ones. I am having some issues with this new files, because they are executed late and my last API call get a 401 error as the response. When I touch the button to navigate to the following screen, my console start showing the following log:

LOG Promise Resolved Ya tengo mi token:
LOG Next step --> Get user name
LOG User name en personal data [object Object]
LOG este es mi user id EtRAEIrIAnM3wZw8VqAd7Wag69D2
LOG Promise Resolved Ya tengo mi token y User Name: [object Object]
LOG Next step --> API Call
LOG Este es el dato que acabo de obtener en la funcion UserNameTrial22
LOG Mi userToken eyJraWQiOiJkRDNqekJETm....
LOG {"code": undefined, "columnNumber": undefined, "config": {"adapter": [Function xhrAdapter], "data": "{"username":{"_U":1,"_V":1,"_W":"","_X":null},"document_number":"666666","gender":"M","names":"M","last_names":"M","birthdate":"11/01/1999","order":"12345678910"}", "headers": {"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, /", "Authorization": "Bearer ",...., "message": "Request failed with status code 401",
The two values from other functions that I need to send the data to the API are 'username' and 'user_token' You can see that my username is sent to the API with the value of = {"_U":1,"_V":1,"_W":"","_X":null} and not as 'UserNameTrial22'. Also the Bearer token is not concat in a good way.It takes the value that has been asigned at the begin (let user_token = '') instead of 'eyJraWQiOiJkRDNqekJETm....'.

I attached the main screen and also the js files with the functions to get 'username' and 'user_token'.

Thank you in advance

```js
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    Button,
} from 'react-native';

import { COLORS, SIZES, FONTS, icons, images} from "../../constants"
import FormInput from '../../components/FormInput';
import FormButton from '../../components/FormButton';
import { AuthContext } from '../../navigation/AuthProvider';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import axios from 'axios';


let user_token = '';
let nextStep = '';
let username = '';
let data = 'userName';

const RENAPER_PERSONAL_DATA = ( {navigation} ) => {

    //Obtener mi UserName
    const { user } = useContext(AuthContext); 

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [document_number, setDocumentNumber] = useState();
    const [gender, setGender] = useState();
    const [last_names, setLastNames] = useState();
    const [birthdate, setBirthDate] = useState();
    const [names, setNames] = useState();
    const [order, setOrder] = useState();


    const submitUserdata = async () => {
        firestore()
            .collection('UserData')
            .doc(user.uid)
            .update ({
                userDoc: document_number,
                userGender: gender,
                userLastname: last_names,
                userDate: birthdate,
                userFirstname: names,
                userTramitnum: order
            })
            .then ( () => {
           //     console.log('Se agrega nueva INFO al user ID!')
            })
            .catch((error) => {
          //      console.log(error)
            });
    };

  


    async function getUserNameInfo() {
        user_token = await getCredentials()
        
        console.log('Promise Resolved Ya tengo mi token: ' + user_token)
        console.log('Next step --> Get user name')
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve ( username = getSpecUserData(data, user.uid),
               )
            }, 10)

            console.log('User name en personal data ' + username)
            
        })
    };

    async function makeAPICall() {
        const result = await getUserNameInfo()
        console.log('Promise Resolved Ya tengo mi token y User Name: ' + username)
        console.log('Next step --> API Call')
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve ( onSubmitFormHandler(), submitUserdata())
            }, 500)
        })
    };

    async function callForButton() {
        const result = await makeAPICall()
       console.log('API Request completed')
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve ( navigation.navigate(nextStep) )
            }, 500)
        })
    }

     // API Rest POST - Personal Data -  
const onSubmitFormHandler = async (event) => {
      setIsLoading(true);
                
    return axios.post("myurl2.com", 
            
             {username,
            document_number,
            gender,
            names,
            last_names,
            birthdate,
            order
             },
          
            {headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${user_token}`}}
            )
             .then(response => {
                 // If request es 200
                console.log(response.data);
                 setIsLoading(false);                
                nextStep = response.data.next_action;
                username = ''; 
                 
              })
              .catch((error) => {
               console.log(error.toJSON());
                setIsLoading(false);                
                nextStep = 'RENAPER_PERSONAL_DATA';
             });

           };

    return (
        <View style={{
            ...........
            
            onPress={() => {
                callForButton()
            }}
            disabled={isLoading}
            />
            </View>
            </View>
    );
}
export default RENAPER_PERSONAL_DATA;
```

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import {useState, useContext} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

async function getCredentials () {


        let user_token = '';
        //Data para credenciales
        const client_id =  "xxxxxx";
        const client_secret =  "xxxxxx";
        
       
         axios.post('myurl.com', 
        
        {client_id,client_secret})   
        .then(response => {
           //console.log('Corriendo la funcion ' + response.data.access_token);
           //setUserToken(response.data.access_token);
           user_token = response.data.access_token;
           console.log(' Mi userToken ' + user_token)
           
           
         })   
        .catch((error) => {
           //console.log(error);   
        });
        return user_token;
      }
        
        



export {getCredentials}
```

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import { AuthContext } from '../navigation/AuthProvider';
import {useState, useContext} from 'react';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';


   const getSpecUserData = async (data, user) => {
       let username = '';
       console.log('este es mi user id ' + user)
        function callUserData(documentSnapshot) {
            return documentSnapshot.get(data); }
        firestore()
        .collection('UserData')
        .doc(user)
        .get()
        .then(
            documentSnapshot => callUserData(documentSnapshot)
        )
        .then(callUserData => { 
            username = callUserData;
            console.log('Este es el dato que acabo de obtener en la funcion ' + username)            
          });
          return username
        
    };
 


export {getSpecUserData}
```